# How to read a single line from a text file, split it into 2 lines, and output the 2 lines to another text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I want a batch code which would do these:

1. Load all the content of a text file into a variable. The content is just 1 line.
2. Then break that 1 line into 2 parts.
3. Put those 2 parts as new lines into another text file.

Let's say my contents are:

```
Bill Gates was born in 1955. <--When was Bill Gates born?-->
```

So I want a batch file which will take the whole sentence above, into a variable.

Then break it into 2 parts like

1. `Bill Gates was born in 1955.`
2. `<--When was Bill Gates born?-->`

Then import those 2 lines to another text file `result.txt` and upon opening, there should be those 2 lines in this manner

```
Bill Gates was born in 1955.
<--When was Bill Gates born?-->
```

Syntax of a sentence:

```
xx yy <--xxy yyz -->
```

New lines in `result.txt`:

```
xx yy
<--xxy yyz -->
```

Please note that the sentences can change. I just gave an example. Sentences must be broken into 2 parts, part 1 before `<--` and part 2 `<--...-->` where `...` is the data.

Comment: This sure sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: LOL, no not at all. I live in India. Here they literally teach nothing about programming. So was trying to learn something on my own. If you want, you can Google up "10th CBSE India computer lessons". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple way to do it:

```
@echo off
type "file.txt" | repl "(.*)(<.*)" "$1\r\n$2" x >"newfile.txt"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

You can use a `for /f` loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

nearly too easy for an answer:

```
set /p line=<in.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=<" %%i in ("%line%") do (
  echo %%i>out.txt
  echo ^<%%j>>out.txt
)
```

Comment: It doesn't do what I want.

Comment: but it does exactly, what you described.

Comment: I want the sentence to be broken down into 2 different sentences. Your code just pulls the sentence. I just tested it again to confirm it.

Comment: just tried it again (copied the code from above): it splits the One-Line-File into a Two-Line-File as requested. What am I missing?

Comment: all three answers (foxidrive's, MC's and mine) are producing the very same output. If foxi's answer makes you more happy than the others, that is ok. But if you say, the others don't work, we'd like to know why and how the output might differ.

Answer (score 0):

First option, substring operations

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem read the first line of input file
    < file.txt set /p "line1="

    rem extract the second line of output file
    set "line2=%line1:*<--=<--%"

    rem extract the first line of output file
    set "line=%line2%"
    :loop
    set "line1=%line1:~0,-1%"
    set "line=%line:~0,-1%"
    if defined line goto loop

    rem generate output file
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    (   echo !line1!
        echo !line2!
    ) > result.txt
    endlocal
```

But this is not very efficient. Better use

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem read the first line of input file
    < file.txt set /p "line="

    rem extract and output the lines
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a in ("%line:<--=|<--%") do (
        echo %%a
        echo %%b
    ) > result.txt
```

**edited** trying to solve problems stated in comments

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem prepare the sample file to be readed
    >file.txt echo Bill Gates was born in 1955. ^<--When was Bill Gates born?--^>

    rem read the first line of input file
    < file.txt set /p "line="

    rem extract and output the lines
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a in ("%line:<--=|<--%") do (
        echo %%a
        echo %%b
    ) > result.txt

    rem show the result
    type result.txt
```

Comment: It doesn't do what I want.

Comment: @PawanKartik, for me, tested against your data, this (both codes) does what you asked for. If this is not what you want, maybe you should change the question to reflect what is what you want or, at least, indicate how the obtained result differs from what you expect to obtain.

Comment: I want the sentence to be broken down into 2 different sentences. Your code just pulls the sentence. I just tested it again to confirm it.

Comment: @PawanKartik, sorry, but for me it works. Please, test the last code i've included in answer. It is the same code, but it will generate the input file, read it and show the output. Maybe there is some encoding problem with files.